# Type error using combination of mypy and boto3 stubs

Tags: python, boto3, mypy, python-typing

I am using typed python in AWS. (mypy and boto3 stubs)

I am new at typing, so I will need your advice and explanation.

I have one function like this:

```
def select_time_range() -> dict[str, datetime]:

    try:
        current_datetime = datetime.now()
        datetime_one_day_before = current_datetime - timedelta(days=1)
        datetime_24_hours_ago = current_datetime - timedelta(hours=24)

        report_timerange_choice = {
            'previous_day': {
                'from': datetime(datetime_one_day_before.year, datetime_one_day_before.month, datetime_one_day_before.day,
                                 0, 0),
                'to': datetime(current_datetime.year, current_datetime.month, current_datetime.day, 0, 0)
            },
            'last_24_hours': {

                    'from': datetime(datetime_24_hours_ago.year, datetime_24_hours_ago.month, datetime_24_hours_ago.day, datetime_24_hours_ago.hour, datetime_24_hours_ago.minute),
                    'to': datetime(current_datetime.year, current_datetime.month, current_datetime.day, current_datetime.hour, current_datetime.minute),
                }
            }

    except Exception as e:
        LOGGER.error(e)
        raise e

    return report_timerange_choice[TIMEFRAME_PICKER]
```

This function is returning dict like this:
`{'from': datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 21, 0, 0)`
'to':

```
 datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 22, 0, 0)}
```

Then I have function like this where I am passing this dict to the function as a parameter. The thing is, **describe_events()** function is expecting **timeframe* as a *type **DateTimeRangeTypeDef**, but it is getting **dict[str, datetime]"**. How can I "change a type" or what I need to do to write correctly?

```
def get_account_events(timeframe: dict[str, datetime]) -> DescribeEventsResponseTypeDef:
    try:
        #DAILY
        daily_events = health_client.describe_events(

            filter={
                'startTimes': [timeframe]
                
            }
        )

    except Exception as e:
        LOGGER.error(e)
        raise e

    return daily_events
```

When I change the type from

**dict[str, datetime]**

to

**DateTimeRangeTypeDef**

in first function, it is complaining that it is a type **dict[str, datetime]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(to clarify, I assume that we're talking about `health_client = boto3.client('health')`)

In stubs it is defined as

```py
TimestampTypeDef = Union[datetime, str]
...
DateTimeRangeTypeDef = TypedDict(
    "DateTimeRangeTypeDef",
    {
        "from": NotRequired[TimestampTypeDef],
        "to": NotRequired[TimestampTypeDef],
    },
)
```

The easiest way to see the stubs is to `pip install` corresponding stubs package (e.g. `pip install 'boto3-stubs[health]'`) and examine the contents of its folder (e.g. `grep -rn DateTimeRangeTypeDef ./venv/lib/python3.XX/site-packages/mypy_boto3_health/`), then go to the file where it is defined and watch. It works for any service, replace `health` with a service name - the one you use to instantiate a client - in the text above.

So just use `DateTimeRangeTypeDef` instead of `dict[str, datetime]`. You may need to annotate the outer dictionary. The following passes type checking cleanly (I took the liberty to fix a couple of almost-definitely-mistakes like `raise e` inside handler, but beware that catch-all `except Exception` is weird here, and `LOGGER.error` does not print traceback by default, you may want to use `LOGGER.exception` or `LOGGER.error(..., exc_info=True)` instead).

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import logging
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Final, Literal, TypeAlias

import boto3

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from mypy_boto3_health.type_defs import (
        DateTimeRangeTypeDef,
        DescribeEventsResponseTypeDef,
    )

health_client: Final = boto3.client("health")
LOGGER: Final = logging.getLogger(__name__)
TimeFramePickerT: TypeAlias = Literal["previous_day", "last_24_hours"]
TIMEFRAME_PICKER: Final[TimeFramePickerT] = "last_24_hours"


def select_time_range() -> DateTimeRangeTypeDef:
    try:
        current_datetime = datetime.now()
        datetime_one_day_before = current_datetime - timedelta(days=1)
        datetime_24_hours_ago = current_datetime - timedelta(hours=24)

        report_timerange_choice: dict[TimeFramePickerT, DateTimeRangeTypeDef] = {
            "previous_day": {
                "from": datetime(
                    datetime_one_day_before.year,
                    datetime_one_day_before.month,
                    datetime_one_day_before.day,
                    0,
                    0,
                ),
                "to": datetime(
                    current_datetime.year,
                    current_datetime.month,
                    current_datetime.day,
                    0,
                    0,
                ),
            },
            "last_24_hours": {
                "from": datetime(
                    datetime_24_hours_ago.year,
                    datetime_24_hours_ago.month,
                    datetime_24_hours_ago.day,
                    datetime_24_hours_ago.hour,
                    datetime_24_hours_ago.minute,
                ),
                "to": datetime(
                    current_datetime.year,
                    current_datetime.month,
                    current_datetime.day,
                    current_datetime.hour,
                    current_datetime.minute,
                ),
            },
        }
    except Exception as e:
        LOGGER.exception(e)
        raise

    return report_timerange_choice[TIMEFRAME_PICKER]


def get_account_events(
    timeframe: DateTimeRangeTypeDef,
) -> DescribeEventsResponseTypeDef:
    try:
        daily_events = health_client.describe_events(
            filter={
                "startTimes": [timeframe],
            }
        )
    except Exception as e:
        LOGGER.error(e)
        raise

    return daily_events
```

Comment: Thak you for your advice. Just a question, I read the stubs documentation hor health service. There is a type for client like this: HealthClient. Why are you using
Final ?

Comment: @MartinGolis Because it's not intended to be ever reassigned - `Final` infers the most precise type of the assigned value when not parametrized explicitly. In this case it gives `reveal_type` of `mypy_boto3_health.client.HealthClient`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Final

Comment: Thank You for your time, I think I will just dig into documentation because I want to start using correct types right on the beginning of learning. Right now I am little bit confused which types to use so I just need read some stuff I guess